# Why couldn't I bind the listenfd with my public IPv4 address, but I could do that with my public IPv6?

Tags: c, sockets, binding, ipv6, ipv4

Here is my case:

I got my public IPv6 and public IPv4 from https://whatismyipaddress.com/, which were like:

IPv6: 2603:6080:1001:100:2042:**----:----**,

IPv4: 75.177.130.***.

Then I used the code below as a TCP/IP server program:

I could bind the listendfd with the IPv6 address, and could make a connection with it from the same or another computer running a TCP/IP client program (set hints.ai_family = AF_INET6),

but I could NOTbind the listendfd with IPv4 addrese, nor connect to it (set hints.ai_family = AF_INET).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define LISTENQ 10
#define MAXLINE 8000

int open_listenfd(char *port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *listp, *p;
    int s, listenfd, optval=1;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1];
    
    // Get a list of potential server addresses
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_ADDRCONFIG; 
    hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

    s = getaddrinfo("75.177.130.***", port, &hints, &listp);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Walk the list for one that we can bind to
    for(p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

        switch(p->ai_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
                printf("bind: family=AF_INET addr=%s port=%u\n",
                   inet_ntoa(addr_in->sin_addr),
                   ntohs(addr_in->sin_port));
                break; 
            }
            case AF_INET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) p->ai_addr;
                printf("bind: family=AF_INET6 IP address: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), ipstr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN));
                printf("Port: %i\n", ntohs(addr_in6->sin6_port)); 
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create a socket descriptor
        if ((listenfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol))<0)
            continue;
    
        // Eliminates "Address already in use"l error from bind
        setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval, sizeof(int));

        // Bind the descriptor to the address
        // NULL coundn't bind port 8080, which might have been used by other services 
        if(bind(listenfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;

        fprintf(stderr, "bind error: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        close(listenfd); // Bind failed, try the next
    }
    // Clean up
    freeaddrinfo(listp);
    if(!p) // No address worked
        return -1;

    // Make it a listening socket ready to accept connectionn request
    if(listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0) {
        close(listenfd);
        return -1;
    }
    return listenfd;
}

int main() {
    int lisfd, connfd;
    socklen_t clientlen;
    struct sockaddr_storage clientaddr;
    char client_hostname[MAXLINE], client_port[MAXLINE];

    char *listenport = "8798";
    lisfd = open_listenfd(listenport);
    printf("listenfd: %i\n", lisfd);

    while(1) {
        clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        connfd = accept(lisfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clientlen);
        if (connfd != -1) {
            getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, clientlen, client_hostname, MAXLINE, client_port, MAXLINE, 0);
            printf("accepted connection from(%s %s)\n", client_hostname, client_port);
            close(connfd);
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, I could use my computer's private IPv4 address 192.168.0.1* to do the binding, and have my TCP/IP client program running  another computer with private IPv4 address 192.168.0.5* in my house to connect with it.

But if I had one of my computers use my iPhone's connection, the computer generated different private IPv4 address like 172.20.**.*, and I could NOT make a connection with it from another computer in my house that running TCP/IP client program.

Could anyone explain to me why is this? Any comment is welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps someone is already using that port on the specific interface? What is the error you get?

Comment: You are printing the wrong value after bind.  Use perror to print the value of errno.

Comment: Is the public IPv6 address assigned locally to your machine?

Comment: Thank you all for the comment! To Some programmer dude & Stark: I used perro to print the value of error, it say: can't assign requested address. To dbush: I don't think the public IPv6 address I got from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ assigned locally to my machine, cause almost every time I check my public IP addresses using that webiste, the IPv6 address changes, but the public IPv4 address from that website does NOT change, remains like 75.177.130.***.

Comment: You are asking on the wrong SE site. Go to [su] and search for `CGN` (some people call it `CG-NAT` or CGNAT`). Residential ISPs regularly use this now.

Comment: If your machine is behind a NAT router, you don't bind to the public address, you bind to the private address. The router translates the public address to the private address when it performs port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that IPv4 usually uses NAT and IPv6 doesn’t. That means that your IPv6 address actually belongs to your PC/phone/tablet etc (everybody get billions of IPv6 addresses, so each device gets its own), while your IPv4 address (of which you often get only one) belongs to your NAT router. That is why your PC can’t bind to it.

If you want to listen to an IPv6 address:

- find out your stake local address, with IPv6 you get multiple addresses. You usually have one or more short-lived addresses for privacy, and one stable address. You usually want to listen on the latter
- bind to your local address (or just listen to all addresses, easier!)
- Configure the firewall in your router to allow incoming connections

To listen to IPv4:

- find out what your public address is
- Find out what your internal (private) address is
- Listen on the internal address
- Configure your NAT router to forward a specific port of the public address to a specific port on your internal address
- Configure the firewall in your router to allow incoming connections

I hope this clarifies the difference

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, I appreciated it! One more question: how does everybody get billions of IPv6 addresses? Do you mean billions of public IPv6 addresses (Almost everytime time I used whatismyipaddress.com to find my IP addresses, the IPV6 was different, the IPv4 75.177.130. *** stayed the same  )?

Comment: Btw,  1) I ran my TCP/IP server program on one computer connected to my home network, and ran my TCP/IP client program on another computer that connected to my cellphone network, they cannot connect. 2) I ran TCP/IP server and client programs ran on the same/different computers that connected to my home network, they could connect. So, I think as you said, if I want to allow incoming connections from outside my home network, I need to configure the firewall in my router. (The router probably has a default setting that only allow outgoing connections to the internet.)